# How to correct an Excel formula error

Tags: excel-formula

=O27&" "&IF(D27<>"",VLOOKUP(D27,성취기준1반!$B$4:$C$19,2)&" ","")&IF(E27<>"",VLOOKUP(E27,성취기준1반!$E$4:$F$19,2)&" ","")&IF(F27<>"",VLOOKUP(F27,성취기준1반!$H$4:$I$19,2)&" ","")&IF(G27<>"",VLOOKUP(G27,성취기준1반!$K$4:$L$19,2)&" ","")&IF(H27<>"",VLOOKUP(H27,성취기준1반!$N$4:$O$33,2)&" ","")&IF(I27<>"",VLOOKUP(I27,성취기준1반!$Q$4:$R$33,2)&" ","")&IF(J27<>"",VLOOKUP(J27,성취기준1반!$T$4:$U$33,2)&" ","")&IF(K27<>"",VLOOKUP(K27,성취기준1반!$W$4:$X$33,2)&" ","")&IF(L27<>"",VLOOKUP(L27,성취기준1반!$Z$4:$AA$33,2)&" ","")&IF(M27<>"",VLOOKUP(M27,성취기준1반!$AC$4:$AD$19,2)&" ","")&P27
this is working code

=O28&" "&IF(D28<>"",VLOOKUP(D28,성취기준1반!$B$4:$C$19,2)&" ","")&IF(E28<>"",VLOOKUP(E28,성취기준1반!$E$4:$F$19,2)&" ","")&IF(F28<>"",VLOOKUP(F28,성취기준1반!$H$4:$I$19,2)&" ","")&IF(G28<>"",VLOOKUP(G28,성취기준1반!$K$4:$L$19,2)&" ","")&IF(H28<>"",VLOOKUP(H28,성취기준1반!$N$4:$O$33,2)&" ","")&IF(I28<>"",VLOOKUP(I28,성취기준1반!$Q$4:$R$33,2)&" ","")&IF(J28<>"",VLOOKUP(J28,성취기준1반!$T$4:$U$33,2)&" ","")&IF(K28<>"",VLOOKUP(K28,성취기준1반!$W$4:$X$33,2)&" ","")&IF(L28<>"",VLOOKUP(L28,성취기준1반!$Z$4:$AA$33,2)&" ","")&IF(M28<>"",VLOOKUP(M28,성취기준1반!$AC$4:$AD$19,2)&" ","")&P28
this is doesn't workin code.

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, I understand this is your first question, but it doesn't meet the standard quality expected, please read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to have some guidance. For instance you don't provide the error you actually get, or you don't explain what you're trying to acheive.

Comment: Suggestion : break the non-working formula into its component parts and find which part is causing the error, so for example replace all the vlookups with the result they should give etc etc

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer in terms of a solution, but an answer in terms of the method you could employ to find and solve the issue. Mainly because you have not provided a working verifiable example, data or detail of the actual error.

First I would remove the vlookups and replace them with the expected results - if that then functions as it should then each of the vlookups needs to be tested, if not then check the detail of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate if you can assist by explaining.. "why this doesn't work?" part. It is an error message or the the expected value is _ but I got _ instead.. (:

One thing I noticed is that you don't define what will be the outcome if D28 is "". If you don't define it, it'll return 'FALSE' value instead of a String/text.

In your IF() function, you only say `IF(d28<>"",<DisplayValueFrom성취기준1반>)` it should be  `IF(d28<>"",<DisplayValueFrom성취기준1반>,<DisplaySomeThingElse>)`